# Arquillian testing - How to call a method after all tests are finished

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, jboss-arquillian

I am using ArquillianSuiteDeployment for my project, each sub-project has a Deployments class in which we have two methods - one for creating a shrinkwrap archive of REST classes and other for non-REST classes.

As part of code coverage generation, I am following this **https://developer.jboss.org/thread/206559?tstart=0**

Now, I want to call a servlet just after all the tests are finished. Using @AfterClass annotation is not suitable because It will invoke for each class. Any ideas?

Comment: You can run ur Servlet as a last test, using the InSquence annotation.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have Arquillins suties:

---

```
@ArquillianSuiteDeployment
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ArquillianTestSuite1{

@Test
@InSequence(1)
public void test1(){

}

}
```

---

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ArquillianTestSuite2{

@Test
@InSequence(1)
public void test1(){

}

@Test
    @InSequence(2)
    public void finalTestWithServlet(){
    runYourServletHere();
}
}
```

---

`finalTestWithServlet()` would be the last test to run in the set of suites above.
So you can run the servlet here.

Comment: So this requires to edit all the existing test classes to add the annotation  right?

Comment: We have a huge number of test classes and it is not practical to edit each of them. Do we have any other option?